# PixiJS with new Edge(chrome) version (>=112) animation not work

Tags: google-chrome, pixi.js

my PixiJS game works well on Edge version 111, but the animation becomes super slow in version 112. There is no error in the console.

The strange thing is: If I open the dev tool and open the Element, and I move my mouse over the canvas of the game, the animation work well again. but after the mouse leaves the top of the element, the animation is stuck again. what a strange scenario!

This is my test game app

[image]